# table decoration fails to work

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Here is the view's table I would like to decorate the row one the isoverdeadline is equal to 'yes'

```
<tr <?php
        if(strcmp($isoverdeadline,'yes'))
        {
          echo ' style:"background-color:#CC3300"';
        }
      ?>
      >
        <td width="250" <?php
          if(strcmp($isoverdeadline,'yes'))
          {
        echo ' style:"background-color:#fff"';
          }
          ?>
        ><?php echo $projectname; ?> </td>
        <td width="70"<?php
          if(strcmp($isoverdeadline,'yes'))
          {
        echo ' style:"background-color:#CC3300"';
          }
          ?>
        ><?php echo $ticketid; ?></td>
        <td <?php
        if(strcmp($isoverdeadline,'yes'))
        {
          echo ' style:"background-color:#fff"';
        }
        ?>
        ><?php echo $subject; ?></td>
        <td<?php
          if(strcmp($isoverdeadline,'yes'))
          {
        echo ' style:"background-color:#fff"';
          }
        ?>
        ><?php echo $startdate; ?></td>
        <td<?php
        if(strcmp($isoverdeadline,'yes'))
        {
          echo ' style:"background-color:#fff"';
        }
        ?>><?php echo $deadline; ?></td>  
      </tr>
```

Here is part of the code in the controler in which project_info array will be set to be seen in the view.

```
if($this->is_proj_due($project_info['deadline'])<0) //deadline is over
{
$project_info['isoverdeadline']='yes';
 }
else
{
$project_info['isoverdeadline']='no';
}
return $project_info;


function is_proj_due($due_date)
    {
        $now=new DateTime('now');
        $dnow=$now->format('Y-m-d');
        $due=$due_date->format('Y-m-d');
        $interval =(strtotime($dnow)-strtotime($due));
    print_r($interval);
    return $interval;
    }
```

Something goes wrong as I see nothing changed; I guess it's the time comparison that causes it. I am thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> [`strcmp`] returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, ***and 0 if they are equal.***
>
> http://php.net/strcmp

If the strings are equal, `0` is returned. `0` is equal to `false`. So the condition does the exact opposite of what you expect.

For yes/no values, don't use `"yes"`/`"no"`. Use the boolean truth values `true` or `false`.

```
$project_info['isOverDeadline'] = true;

if ($project_info['isOverDeadline']) ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't use a boolean value instead, I was stuuupeed. Very good spot!.

Comment: Hel-llo, I corrected as what you tell me but now my page becomes blank

Comment: Also your `echo` should not be `style:"background-color:#CC3300"` but `style="background-color:#CC3300"`